# Application hanging on customer machine

Tags: c#, debugging, .net-4.0, cpu-usage, freeze

My .NET 4.0 Application is hanging on a customer Machine. The same customer has a Windows 7 where it hangs and a Windows XP where it is working very fast with no hangers. Now, I see, that on the Windows 7 machine when it is hanging the process of my exe needs 50% of the CPU.

I am now searching a way that I can find out, why it needs this CPU Time and hope to get the reason for the hangers. What can I do to get out the reason of the hangers and the high CPU usage on the customer machine?

I have only a release version of the app and no visual studio on the machine.

Comment: Sorry, but where is the question?

Comment: Find out if it always hogs 50% cpu after the customers does a specific action. Then try to find the problem via code reading. (Or get Windows 7 to debug :P)

Comment: There are different actions which causes the hangs. And the same action do not always cause a hang. Is there a way that I can attach a Debugger on the customer machine - Perhaps with uploading the pdb-files?

Comment: You won't be able to easily debug into their machine. Get a snapshot by taking a dumpfile, as per my answer below.

Comment: Is that 50% CPU on a single-processor machine? Or perhaps one core is pinned on a dual processor machine? Two cores on a quad core machine? I've seen this behavior when moving multi-threaded code from a single-core machine to a quad-core. Two threads end up in a busy-wait deadlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the customer to create a dump file of the process and send it to you. As they are on Windows 7 this is very easy.

Open Task Manager, right click on the process and select 'Create Dump File'

The dump file *may* be large so get them to zip it before emailing it to you.

As you are using .NET4 you can then open this file in Visual Studio 2010 and you will have a snapshot of the client process, included managed data, threads etc. which should help diagnose your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Microsoft's SysInternals tools

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals

Process monitor or explorer should give you the info you need.

Being a Win7 machine my guess is that its user priviledges.